# How can I convert MySQL data to JSON more easily?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is there any tool that can be used to convert MySQL table data to JSON?

Right now I am using this technique. It is good for short queries, but I have a database with some 124 tables in it with some really complex queries. In that case it is really time consuming.

```
<?php 
include("Conf.php");
//$q = "Select * From oc_category WHERE status='1'";
$q = "Select * FROM `opencartpizza`.`oc_currency` WHERE status ='1'";
$run = mysql_query($q);
$a = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
    $a[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

This technique seems boring and old style. Let me know if there is any converter or tool that can quickly convert or otherwise be helpful for this.

**Question Edited**

I don't want to put the entire database in JSON, but just some specific entities on demand.

Comment: That's the only _technique_ to convert an `array` into `json`

Comment: But i have a database with 124 tables in it and some complex queries. So thats much time taking

Comment: Set your table names into an array, then loop through the array running the code in your question, substituting the table in each run.

Comment: So, you want to dump your *entire* database as a JSON file?  What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: So, create a separate function to convert array->json. And call that function  every time.

Comment: If you switch from `mysql_*` to either MySQLi or PDO, there is a `fetch_all`/`fetchAll` method that would avoid the `while` loop.  Other than that, if you want a JSON file, you need to build an array/object and use `json_encode`.

Comment: I edit my question. Hope any one can get idea easily now